Issue with Route Pathnames Not Updating Correctly in Next.js Project
I have a problem with my React Next.js project. The problem is in routing. When I start the server, the home page link is "/" and in the console log, I see the pathname as "/". When I go to the catalog page, I still see the pathname as "/". When I start the server on the catalog page, I see the pathname as "/catalog" in the console log. Then, when I go to the home page, I still see the pathname "/catalog" in the console log.
I need change styles of header on different pages.

Can you share your code and produce a minimal example?

Clarify how you are handling routing and updating the pathname. Include relevant code snippets.
